# Convert float to comma-separated string

Tags: python

How would I convert a float into its 'accounting form' --

```
100028282.23 --> 100,028,282.23
100028282 --> 100,028,282.00
```

Is there a python method that does this?

Comment: Storing monetary amounts as floats might not be such a good in the first place.

Comment: Can you explain why it is so? I'm curious about this since in my opinion floats make it easy to calculate with.

Comment: @ClementOseiTano floats round so aren't great for financial calculations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`locale.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.format) function to do this:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
'en_US.utf8'
>>> locale.format("%.2f", 100028282.23, grouping=True)
'100,028,282.23'
```

Note that you have to give the precision: `%.2f`

Alternatively you can use the [`locale.currency()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.currency) function, which follow the [`LC_MONETARY`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.LC_MONETARY) settings:

```
>>> locale.currency(100028282.23)
'$100028282.23'
```

Answer (score 24):

As an alternative to [beerbajay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677386/577088)'s excellent answer, simple string formatting works in 2.7+, without requiring an import:

```
>>> '{0:,.2f}'.format(24322.34)
'24,322.34'
```

Answer (score 3):

For monetary applications, the *decimal* module is a good choice for floating point arithmetic.  To display decimal floats with commas, see the [*moneyfmt*](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes) recipe:

```
def moneyfmt(value, places=2, curr='', sep=',', dp='.',
             pos='', neg='-', trailneg=''):
    """Convert Decimal to a money formatted string.

    places:  required number of places after the decimal point
    curr:    optional currency symbol before the sign (may be blank)
    sep:     optional grouping separator (comma, period, space, or blank)
    dp:      decimal point indicator (comma or period)
             only specify as blank when places is zero
    pos:     optional sign for positive numbers: '+', space or blank
    neg:     optional sign for negative numbers: '-', '(', space or blank
    trailneg:optional trailing minus indicator:  '-', ')', space or blank

    >>> d = Decimal('-1234567.8901')
    >>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$')
    '-$1,234,567.89'
    >>> moneyfmt(d, places=0, sep='.', dp='', neg='', trailneg='-')
    '1.234.568-'
    >>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$', neg='(', trailneg=')')
    '($1,234,567.89)'
    >>> moneyfmt(Decimal(123456789), sep=' ')
    '123 456 789.00'
    >>> moneyfmt(Decimal('-0.02'), neg='<', trailneg='>')
    '<0.02>'

    """
    q = Decimal(10) ** -places      # 2 places --> '0.01'
    sign, digits, exp = value.quantize(q).as_tuple()
    result = []
    digits = map(str, digits)
    build, next = result.append, digits.pop
    if sign:
        build(trailneg)
    for i in range(places):
        build(next() if digits else '0')
    build(dp)
    if not digits:
        build('0')
    i = 0
    while digits:
        build(next())
        i += 1
        if i == 3 and digits:
            i = 0
            build(sep)
    build(curr)
    build(neg if sign else pos)
    return ''.join(reversed(result))
```